# Angular FormControl does not update view when setValue

Tags: angular, angular-material, form-control

I am building a generic **selector component** with Angular Material. When setting the value manually it works ok but, if I update form value from typescript, the view does not reflect that change.

### selector.component.html

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
  <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
  <mat-select
    [formControl]="formControl"
    (valueChange)="onChange($event)"
    multiple
  >
    <mat-select-trigger>
      {{ !!selectedData.length ? selectedData[0][elementLabel] : '' }}
      <span *ngIf="selectedData.length > 1" class="additional-selection">
        (+{{ selectedData.length - 1 }}
        {{ selectedData?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others' }})
      </span>
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let element of data; trackBy: trackByFunction"
      [value]="element"
      >{{ element[elementLabel] }}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

### selector.component.ts

```js
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  Output,
} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'selector',
  templateUrl: './selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./selector.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class SelectorComponent {
  @Input() data: any[] = [];
  @Input() set init(value: any[]) {
    this.selectedData = value;
  }
  @Input() label: string = '';
  @Input() elementLabel: string = '';
  @Output() onChangeEvent: EventEmitter<any[]> = new EventEmitter();
  selectionDisplayText = '';
  formControl = new FormControl([]);

  get selectedData(): any[] {
    return this.formControl.value;
  }

  set selectedData(data: any[]) {
    this.formControl.setValue(data);
  }

  trackByFunction(item: any): string {
    return item[this.elementLabel];
  }

  onChange = (data: any[]) => {
    this.selectedData = data;
    this.onChangeEvent.emit(this.selectedData);
  };
}
```

When I try to update select values from parent component (using `init` input), the code reaches `set selectedData` method and formControl value is set OK, but the view displays an empty select. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: You’re using onPush. Does it work when you remove that?

Comment: No, it doesn't affect

Comment: I think it would be better to set the value from init in the ngOnInit function. It sounds like a changeDetection problem to me. Does this help? https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

Instead of using `formControl` (which complicated things) I used `ngModel` to set the `mat-select` data.

```html
<mat-select
    (valueChange)="onChange($event)"
    [ngModel]="selection"
    [compareWith]="compareFn"
    multiple
>
```

My **problem** was that `mat-select` compares objects by **reference** ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54020212/1974681)), so I needed to add the `compareWith` function to compare based on property. In my case:

```js
compareFn = (obj1: any, obj2: any) => {
    return obj1[this.elementLabel] === obj2[this.elementLabel];
};
```

And update the `onChange` function so `selection` is updated:

```js
onChange = (data: any[]) => {
  const value = this.transform(data);
  this.selection = value;
  this.onChangeEvent.emit(value);
};
```

Comment: This solution skirts around the problem. Fundamentally, the Form value should be updating. I think the Value is updating, but the issue is with Control reflecting the Form Value.